# 48 hours before a question can be deleted?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

In [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) is written:

> Questions that have been closed within the past 48 hours cannot be deleted, so as to allow for editing and possible reopening.

I was a bit surprised, because I remember poor quality question getting deleted within minutes via votes to delete. To see if there is any hint during the process of voting to delete I just voted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103846/how-is-l%c3%96ve2d-written-in-c-but-a-lua-library) (at the time of writing this the close was 28 minutes ago, question posted 35 mintes ago).

The tool tip on the "delete" link just says:

> You voted to delete. 2 more votes from other users are needed to delete this post.

No mention of the 48 hour period.

What is wrong? My memory of seeing questions getting deleted via votes within minutes, my interpretation of the Help text, or the help text itself?

Comment: @yivi oh right I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Answer (score 6):

Trusted users (20k reputation) need not to wait (if the question is both closed and scored -3 or lower).

From the [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed

Comment: then I would say Help > Asking - Why and how are questions deleted is incomplete

Answer (score -5):

As I was pointed to in a comment, trusted users do not need to wait for this 48 hours, this is explained in [Help Center > Privileges > access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for trusted users when a post scores -3 or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please flag it for community moderator attention.

That answers part of my question: Yes question can get closed within minutes.

The other part: Is the help text wrong? I would say yes. Privileges > access to moderator tool does mention the 48 hours, and the exception for privileged users, but [Help Center > Asking - Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) is incomplete.