# Immediate deletion of a closed question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

What has happened to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807103/im-a-beginner-can-somebody-explain-to-me)?

It was asked by a newbie, and is definitely sub-standard. However, although I have only dabbled in [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)), it was pretty obvious from the posted code, what was wrong. I answered accordingly.

5 minutes after I answered, it was closed. Fair enough, it is a poor question, but enough code had been posted to see the problem and it had been answered, so clearly not totally unintelligible.

But now comes the hammer. Only minutes later the question was deleted (not by the OP). My understanding was that a closed question can only be deleted at a minimum 48 hours after closure, in order to give the OP a chance to edit the question and have it reopened. Does the 48 hours rule no longer apply? Or am I missing something here?

SO has a reputation amongst newbies for unfriendliness. If we close and immediately delete, without giving the newbie any breathing space to improve, we are hardly helping to counter this reputation.

I realize that newbies should read the help before asking, but even those who do, still have a steep learning curve. Can we really not be a little more helpful?

Just as background, to help understand where I'm coming from: I am 61 and retire in October. I am therefore probably more tolerant than most when it comes to handing on the baton!

---

Just to make things clear, with regards where I got the "48 hours" from, I refer to [the help center article on deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Questions that have been closed within the past 48 hours cannot be deleted, so as to allow for editing and possible [reopening](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions).

There is nothing here to suggest that high rep users/moderators have power to alter the timing. If they can indeed delete early, that begs two questions: firstly, why does the text not say so, and secondly, why are high rep users/moderators given this leeway with no requirement to explain to the OP why, since particularly with regard to newbies, it would be regarded as highly unfriendly?

Edit 2

To judge from the comments, particularly the upvoted ones, you would think that my question was about whether or not the original question should have been deleted. This is not the case. I do believe that the question was right to be deleted. My question was about timing. In particular giving newbies a reasonable time period to respond to comments and improve a question, to the point where it might be worth retaining. (To which see my general caveat in the comments as to whether a newbie is likely to ask any question worth retention.)

Comment: It probably didn't need to be deleted manually at all, it would have been cleaned up by the roomba in enough time, if it wasn't improved. Great example though of a question with a terrible title.

Comment: I honestly don't see how this question adds much to the quality of the questions and answers on this site, regardless of when it is deleted. There are definitely cases of semi-decent questions being deleted too quickly that need to be pointed out, but I'm afraid that this might not be one of them.

Comment: The question has been deleted by three 20k+ users. It is possible for highly downvoted question (-3): https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Deleting things sooner is a reputation-based privilege that also requires a negative score

Comment: Regarding roomba deletion: Please note that roomba only collects question which do not have upvoted answers. That wasn't the case when the question got deleted, but it also wasn't very unlikely that the asker upvotes one of the answers. So if one wouldn't vote to deleted, they have to monitor the question for the next 9 days to make sure that no answer gets upvoted or that the question gets improved.

Comment: Just because a question *can* be answered doesn't always mean it *should* be answered. Where is the long term value for future readers  in that particular poorly constructed question? Polishing turds does not benefit the overall community

Comment: IMO, questions with titles that are unsearchable by users with the given problem shouldn't be answered, without first editing or at minimum suggesting an edit to fix the title. Otherwise, you're just wasting your time. Sure, you're helping one person, but you're throwing away the time that you could have instead used helping dozens, hundreds. At minimum, fix the title. (you also get a badge related to editing and answering posts, if they end up positively received)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Please don't misunderstand me. I was not saying that the question had merit on the site. I was merely asking about the timing of deletion and the degree to which we give OPs (particularly newbies) a chance to improve.

Comment: well, there's also the question of... whether or not *any edit at all* can improve the post to the point where the users casting delete votes think the post wouldn't be worthy of deletion. There's certainly an argument to be made in "How do i resolve this error" when the error states "X should be Y" being not useful regardless of how well it is written, but that's quite subjective (which is why we require multiple votes and allow reversal)

Comment: @KevinB Now we come to the rub. IMHO the chances of a newbie asking any question that has a really useful long term future are almost a priori impossible. The vast majority of newbie questions should be deleted on this basis, even if they are well constructed ,(as this clearly wasn't). This is a separate issue, which has been troubling me for some time. Maybe I'll get around to putting my thoughts down in a separate question.

Comment: and, i agree with you, that often simple questions are too hastily deleted without there being an existing canonical to cover the topic. but. I also think there's a certain point where a question is... so self explanatory that it is beneath existing on this platform. I'm not sure where that line exists in c#, but in javascript for example, asking how to access the property of a 1D object is beneath that line. I'd like to think errors generally sit above it, but should normally be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @KevinB Absolutely right. I only follow C#, SQL, VB and VBA, but the same problems are there. I have never asked a question on this site; not that I know everything, but I have always found a solution by searching. 99% of all questions here shouldn't be asked, if people only searched correctly. This comes down to the crux: should we delete 99% of the questions?

Comment: While this probably should be closed as dup (not the first time one asks for it - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+delete+48+hours) I posted an answer to clarify my reasoning (since the question indirectly calls me out).

Comment: Sometimes deleting question that cannot be improved is a merciful thing to do. It prevents it from accumulating more downvotes. Another additional problem is that poor questions with no long term value that are answered might require more moderation to be removed if the answer is upvoted or accepted. Watching and following those means additional work. If you wanted to help a user with such poor question that cannot be fixed in a meaningful way, you could have posted a comment.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock theoretically you may not even be so far off with that percentage, but practically it would be the death of the site because goodbye ad revenue :) Also, ain't nobody got time for that many deletions. It is finding that middle ground - defining when a question is "good enough" rather than all of them needing to be top tier.

Comment: @Gimby I totally agree with you.  It does trouble me though.  I know it has been unsuccessfully raised before, but personally I feel the site should be split in two, junior and senior (to which the right to post questions requires reasonable rep).  Questions on the junior site would automatically die after a few weeks, unless high rep users "promoted" them to the senior site.  On this basis there would be no need for downvoting (perceived by newbies as unfriendly) on the junior site, since the questions will die anyway. But there is still the same traffic for ads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why I voted to delete the question: while my trolling side says that waiting for the post to collect dozens of downvotes (due to complete lack of "show research" and non-specific title) was against it I still voted to delete. I believe -3-6 range of votes on a question is somewhat recoverable from Q-ban by asking good questions, but if one of the questions gets -10 or even lower score the account would be essentially non-recoverably banned.

Why I could vote to delete: [48 hours before a question can be deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393726/48-hours-before-a-question-can-be-deleted) links to [help on privileges for 20K+ users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed

Why I did not do any alternative actions: there is no edits that would make that question unique on SO. Even if I would try to edit the post I'm afraid it will simply endup offensive for the user - MRE would be one line and to "show research" link to the documentation of particular method would be needed. I can't see how resulting "This is my code where I pass X. Documentation says 'pass Y'. Why this happens?" question would not give me site wide suspension.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer highlighted another thing that I didn't realize, namely that closed questions can still be voted on. I don't think that I have ever seen this in practice. In my experience, once a question has been closed, it gets ignored by most people. Does this in fact happen often - closed questions attracting further downvotes?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Yes, it does. These actions are not mutually exclusive

Comment: FWIW I would have voted to delete this question immediately as well.